# Programmatic way to collect comments for Android App

Tags: android

I released and Android app, and I want to be able to collect comments in some sort of programmatic fashon.  I've looked around the the web and can't seem to find any Google API or any 3rd party service.  Does anyone have any suggestions or know something I don't?

I was thinking about writing some sort of HTML scraper to just extract them from the developer console, but I wanted to get some feedback before I start that little adventure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unofficial [Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) (It is still called like that).

It scrapes the content from the play store, so you can do all kind of things with it:

E.g. get the description, app logo, comments etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  This looks like it will do the trick.